# Ember.TextField valueBinding with keyUp Override

Tags: ember.js

Why doesn't TextField valueBind correctly when overriding the keyUp function? Example here http://jsfiddle.net/z5SNW/3/ .Basically I am alerting the value of the TextField whenever enter is pressed or the user clicks the button.  The problem is pressing the button doesn't show the actual value until you focus out of the text field, and then click the button.

I can hack it by putting an else into the keyUp function and set the value there, but that doesn't seem right to me.  I think I am just missing something really simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By overriding `keyUp` the value of the TextField is only set when the `change` event is fired (on focus lost), see [code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_support.js#L34-36).

If you use the available `insertNewline` for your handling of enter, everything works: http://jsfiddle.net/z5SNW/6/.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.TextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    valueBinding: 'App.TextValue.value',
    insertNewline: function() {
        alert('Submitted: ' + App.TextValue.get('value'));
    }
});

App.TextValue = Em.Object.create({
    value: ''
});

App.SubmitButton = Em.Button.extend({
    click: function() {
        alert(App.TextValue.get('value'));
    }
});​
```

Or you keep your implementation of `keyUp` (if you plan to act on other keyCode's as well, but then you have to call `this.interpretKeyEvents(event);`, see http://jsfiddle.net/z5SNW/8/.

Comment: I knew it was something simple that I was missing, Thanks!